# Sharing a model in multiple components

Tags: typescript, angular6

I'm trying to share a model with multiple components.

In my component:

```
public myModel: MyModel;
```

This is my form view, with multiple components in it:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="accordion">
      <app-details-1 [myModel]="myModel"></app-details-1>
      <app-details-2 [myModel]="myModel"></app-details-2>
      <app-details-3 [myModel]="myModel"></app-details-3>
```

In my components I do something like this:

```
@Input() myModel: MyModel;
```

In my forms in the components I would like to bind my inputs to myModel:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" name="someRadioButton" [(ngModel)]="myModel.someValue"> Yes
</label>
```

However, when loading the page, I get parsing errors cause myModel is empty.
I also have some dependencies in my component based on the model:

```
this.itemSubscription = this.someService.get(this.myModel.id).subscribe(item => {
      this.item = item
    });
```

This also fails, because myModel is empty...

These are the errors:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

And the call to my API

```
GET https://myApiUrl/api/item/undefined <--- this is the id from myModel
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you instantiated your model before accessing it's properties into child components?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: do you receive an undefined error?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `myModel` is not instantiated, so when you try to access one of its property it fails because it's undefined.

In typescript you can use this syntax

```
public myModel: MyModel;
```

to define the type of a variable, in this case `myModel` variable will be of type `MyModel`.
So this instruction is only a declaration, you are saying that a particular memory address is referenced by `myModel` name.

Then to create a variable of type `MyModel` you need to instantiate it with `new MyModel()`.

So the extended typescript syntax to do this is

```
public myModel: MyModel = new MyModel();
```

This is equal to:

- `myModel` is a variable of type `MyModel`
- `myModel` is a public variable
- assign a new instance of `MyModel` to `myModel` variable

Now, when you create an instance in the same line of a type declaration you can omit this last thing, letting the compiler to infere the object type. So writing

```
public myModel = new MyModel();
```

is a contracted form that will lead to

```
public myModel: MyModel = new MyModel();
```

Comment: Should I do this, instead of public myModel: MyModel;?